# How to update barchart in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart

I have bar chart, with a lot of custom properties ( label, linewidth, edgecolor)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax  = plt.gca()

x = np.arange(5)
y = np.random.rand(5)

bars = ax.bar(x, y, color='grey', linewidth=4.0)

ax.cla()
x2 = np.arange(10)
y2 = np.random.rand(10)
ax.bar(x2,y2)
plt.show()
```

With 'normal' plots I'd use `set_data()`, but with barchart I got an error: `AttributeError: 'BarContainer' object has no attribute 'set_data'`

I don't want to simply update the heights of the rectangles, I want to plot totally new rectangles. If I use ax.cla(), all my settings (linewidth, edgecolor, title..) are lost too not only my data(rectangles), and to clear many times, and reset everything makes my program laggy. If I don't use `ax.cla()`, the settings remain, the program is faster (I don't have to set my properties all the time), but the rectangles are drawn of each other, which is not good.

Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your case, `bars` is only a `BarContainer`, which is basically a list of `Rectangle` patches. To just remove those while keeping all other properties of `ax`, you can loop over the bars container and call remove on all its entries or as ImportanceOfBeingErnest pointed out simply remove the full container:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax  = plt.gca()

x = np.arange(5)
y = np.random.rand(5)

bars = ax.bar(x, y, color='grey', linewidth=4.0)

bars.remove()
x2 = np.arange(10)
y2 = np.random.rand(10)
ax.bar(x2,y2)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Why removing the bars one-by-one and not directly remove the complete BarContainer, `bars.remove()`?

Comment: I have tried your solutions: looping thrugh  'bars', and remove bars in one step too.After the new ax.bar(x2,y2) the rectangles are blue again, but my other settings (the not-rectangle related ones of course), like title, y,x lims stayed the same, thanks!